# Compiling Windows Native program in Visual Studio

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, windows-nt

I am trying to develop a native Windows program so I started from
[Pavel Yosifovich's video](https://youtu.be/EKBvLTuI2Mo?si=BvUxk7A2rxyLB3E1&t=1711). I wrote the `simple.cpp` program as shown in the video, and set options of Visual Studio as explained (SubSystem:Native, C++ security check and runtime checks disabled), but my program doesn't compile and reports `LNK2019` errors.

```c
#include<Windows.h>
#include<winternl.h>

// compiler will handle the import of following prototypes
extern "C" {
    NTSTATUS NTAPI NtTerminateProcess(_In_opt_ HANDLE ProcessHandle, NTSTATUS ExitStatus);
    NTSTATUS NTAPI NtDelayExecution(_In_ BOOLEAN Alertable, _In_opt_ PLARGE_INTEGER DelayInterval);
    NTSTATUS NTAPI NtDrawText(_In_ PUNICODE_STRING Text);
}

#define NtCurrentProcess() ( (HANDLE)(LONG_PTR) -1 )

extern "C" void NTAPI NtProcessStartup(PPEB peb){
    // peb is accessed here by default!
    UNICODE_STRING text;
    // create unicode string
    RtlInitUnicodeString(&text, L"Hello from NativeApps!");
    // show message in boot  
    NtDrawText(&text);
    LARGE_INTEGER interval;
    interval.QuadPart = -10000 * 5000;
    NtDelayExecution(FALSE, &interval);
    // we must close native programs
    NtTerminateProcess(NtCurrentProcess(), 0);
}
```

[image: Errors]

If programs compiles correctly, by cpoying it to system32 folder and adding the program name to `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Session Manager\BootExecute`, we expect following out:

[image: Program in a HyperV windows machine]

I searched some books and Google, but couldn't find any helpful resource for Windows native programming.

Note: Native programs aren't launched as normal C and C++ programs(from `main` function). Their entry function is `NtProcessStartup`

Comment: Where is your "int main()", and what do you think your #define does? Before diving into the windows API make sure you at least know how to create a basic C++ executable. There should be no reason to define your NtProcessStartup function like that. In the end calling the windows API is like calling most other libraries and it involves a lot of reading the API documentation : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/processthreadsapi/nf-processthreadsapi-terminateprocess

Comment: This is a native windows program and doesn't need main(). Also the mentioned errors are with compilation process and not executing.

Comment: Microsoft loves having programs without `main`. For example if you ask MSVC to build a *Windows Desktop Application* , it will give you a skeleton having `WinMain` instead of `main`... **But**, the MSVC wizard also declared in the link options that it will be the program entry point! I have never user the Native API, but I assume that *you* are responsible to declaring `NtProcessStartup` to be the entry point. If I have correctly understood this [sysinternals] page, the DDK could help...

Comment: But *truely native* programs are seldom  used in real life. What is your goal here (apart from learning...)?

Comment: @SergeBallesta Just want to learn about windows internals and the program was very simple, I thought I can execute it.

Comment: When using a non-standard entry point, you will have to let the linker know. That's what the [`/ENTRY`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/entry-entry-point-symbol) linker option is for.

Comment: @0xmijix Well when I write a console app even on windows it just uses "main()" but maybe I should have said "main entry point".  And it is perfectly fine to use the windows API from such an console app too. And yes all the errors are compilation errors since the code doesn't make sense

Comment: *"all the errors are compilation errors since the code doesn't make sense"* - They are not. MSVC reports compiler errors with a `C` prefix. Since there is none, it is obvious that the code made perfect sense to the compiler.

Comment: A side note: [Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors).

Comment: @PepijnKramer these are actually linker errors (not compilation ones). And I don't understand why you wrote that _"the code doesn't make sense"_. It seems to attempt to show a hello world text. I am not familiar with native applications though to know whether it is correct.

Comment: This "native" way of building Windows applications using DDK, device-driver level APIs, and "Nt" prefixed APIs is not how any sane person writes a Windows app. Heck, when I think "native Windows", I assume an app with a WinMain and a GetMessage/DispatchMessage loop.  Or a console app with a main function.  Is this just for learning?

Comment: @wohlstad It doesn't make sense to me, bcause I cannot see how this would result in executable code. Also C++ seems to be more of a problem here then help since all the code is just "C" in the first place. But I think most of the confussion is about OP not being clear about WHAT he wants.

Comment: Only speculating here, but I believe the OP would like `NtProcessStartup` to be the entry point, and when run it should display the text via `NtDrawText` (as a native window application).

Comment: @PepijnKramer *"It doesn't make sense to me"* - Right, but why then comment?

Comment: I edited the question with expected output and how it executes. I think what I expect is more clarified now.

Comment: You are getting the error on main() because you link the C runtime library, Project > Properties > Linker > Advanced > "Entry point" setting.  You are getting the NtXxx errors because you don't link an import library that defines these functions.  Intentionally omitted by Microsoft (they *really* don't want you to do this, can't guarantee that future versions of Windows are compatible), I think the WDK has ntdll.lib.  The WDK is in general the tool of choice to do anything native, like writing device drivers.  Or use LoadLibrary + GetProcAddress.

Comment: Since you don't want to link against *any* default libraries (such as the CRT) you need to use the [`/NODEFAULTLIB`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/nodefaultlib-ignore-libraries) linker option (alongside the `/ENTRY` linker option). To resolve the remaining linker errors, you can link against ntdll.lib that's part of the Windows SDK.